# How to ensure that a class methods gets called

Tags: c#

I've got a class that I want make sure the Complete method complete gets called ...somehow.  For example:

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid TransactionId {get; private set;}
    public void Complete(Guid transactionId)
    {
        TransactionId = transactionId;
    }
}
```

How can i ensure that the Complete method gets called by clients?

```
public class Cart
{
    public void Process()
    {
        Order o = new Order();
        // Do stuff
        o.Complete(GetTransactionId());
    }
}
```

The above code seems weak in that its feasible that the complete methods does not get called:

```
public class Cart
{
    public void Process()
    {
        Order o = new Order();
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Heard about events but not too sure if that is the correct solution...Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think the Complete() method won't be called in Process()?

Answer (score 2):

You could make it implement `IDisposable` and always create a new order within a using statement. That way you can control when the `Complete` method gets called.

Comment: Absolutely the right answer. Correctly implemented, this will guarantee that Complete gets called (in all cases, eventually).

Comment: Then, what's the meaning of storing the transaction ID in the object if it's disposing?

Comment: @manji: Hmmm, i guess you could throw on disposing if `complete` wasn't called.

Comment: I don't see it being stored in the object. I see it being supplied as a parameter in a fairly invariant way. There's no reason this could not be encapsulated in the disposal method of the Order if the Order has the right stuff to hand.

Comment: Either way is fine. The order either needs the transaction so it can call complete its self, or it needs to know whether complete was called so it can throw.

Comment: Question.  How should i pass the transactionId to the implemented Dispose method?  The Interface defines parameterless method which wont work is a using block?

Comment: @Fixer: You can't, you'll have to insure the order object has that data so it can use it when disposing. E.g. in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that would *not* get called is if there was an exception or some other behavior that caused it not to progress to the next statement (ie, catastrophic failure).

You can guard against an exception preventing it from happening by putting it in [a `finally` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke0zf0f5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
public void Process()
{
    try {
        Order o = new Order();
        // Do stuff
    } finally { 
        o.Complete(GetTransactionId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to force the user of an Order to remember to complete it, is that it? If it is the user's choice when to call Complete() then that's gonna be hard. I guess that you either want the complete to be automatically done after something else that is done with the order *or* you have to somehow make sure that it will be obvious to the user that he forgot to complete it.

It is hard to know without more details of what an order is and how it is used.